# trouble posting data response to react front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, forms

So I was trying to build a simple react and express webapp following a tutorial that takes user input from HTML, feeds it to chat GPT, and than displays the output on the page.
Most of it seems to be working, however no matter what I try I have not been able to get the response data to display on the webpage despite the fact that it fetches the user input just fine and returns the response to console. What am I doing wrong? the {response} just shows an empty div and no errors are thrown on the front or back end terminals, or that I can see in the developer console. Im new to React, and have very little experience with data/form handling in general.

```
// Front end APP.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'

function App() {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [response, setResponse] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ message }), 
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setResponse(data.message));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <textarea 
          value={message} 
          onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}>      
        </textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <div>{response}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App

// Back end index.js

require("dotenv").config();
const OpenAI = require('openai');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai")
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const port = 3001;

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors());


app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { message } = req.body;
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: `${message}`,
        max_tokens: 2048,
        temperature: 1,
    });
    console.log(response.data)
    if(response.data) {
        if(response.data.choices[0].text){
            {
                 res.json({
                     messaage: response.data.choices[0].text
                 });
            }
        }
    }
});
app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

I'm honestly not sure what to try, because based on every example I've looked at, I cannot discern any reason why my response would not be showing up, especially sense the response is showing up in console, and no errors are thrown.

Comment: What do you get when you console.log API response in the front end?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your returned json object. Btw, no need to use `bodyParser` (which is deprecated):

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { message } = req.body;
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-003",
        prompt: `${message}`,
        max_tokens: 2048,
        temperature: 1,
    });
    
    if(response.data && response.data.choices && response.data.choices.length > 0) {
        return res.json({
            message: response.data.choices[0].text
        });
    }
   res.json({ message: 'No data found' });
});
```